# How do I pass a value to state from another page?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

For routing I use react-navigation.

There are two pages :

1. HomePage (main page).
2. HomePageList(main page only all items in list view)

Need to do so:
When I click on an item from the list on the `HomePageList` page. Must pass a value in state to the `HomePage` page.

Let's say I click on the 12 element on the `HomePageList` page.
On Numerate to state `activeSlide` should be passed 12.

---

There is an array of 6 elements there.
On page - `HomePage`. Slider with pagination . The Index of the object is stored in state. In the `activeslide` value.

Visit `HomePageList` all the same 6 element.Only list and search.

When I click on any element of the `HomePageList`. Occurs `_GoHome`.

```
_GoHome = async ( ) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(HOMEPAGE);
  };
```

As I pass through the function of another `item.index` in state `HomePage`.

I tried to do it this way:
To make a sort of constant `ActiveSlide` in a separate file which you want to save the `item.index`.

Then in `HomePage` to do so:

```
if (ActiveSlide !== null){
      this.setState({
        activeSlide: ActiveSlide
      })
    }else{
      this.setState({
        activeSlide: 0
      })
    }
```

But for some reason doesn't work says:

> Error: ActiveSlide read only

Answer (score 0):

With react navigation you can pass parameters in `navigate()`

On the view that wants to pass the parameter:

`this.props.navigation.navigate(HOMEPAGE, { something: value })`

On the view that wants to receive the paramter:

`value = this.props.navigation.getParam('something')`

See the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)